# Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$. Which of the following statement(s) is/are true?

Tags: real-analysis, examples-counterexamples

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$. Which of the following statement(s) is/are true?

1. There exists a continuous function $f:[a, b]\rightarrow (a,b)$ such that $f$ is one-one.
2. There exists a continuous function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow(a,b)$ such that $f$ is onto.
3. There exists a continuous function $f:(a, b)\rightarrow[a,b]$ such that $f$ is one-one.
4. There exists a continuous function $f:(a, b)\rightarrow[a,b]$ such that $f$ is onto.

I have found an example for option 4: take a compact subset $[c,d]$ of $[a,b]$, find a bijection $f : [c,d] \to [a,b]$, and then extend $f$ to have domain $(a, b)$.

Also 2 can not be correct, because a continuous function on a compact set has compact image.

How to eliminate the others?

Comment: Could you back up your assertions for 2 and 4? What are your examples and proofs?

Comment: 2 can not be true as the interval $[a,b]$  is compact and $f$ is continuous. while in 4 we can find a bijection from a proper subset of (a,b) which is of the form [c,d] to [a,b] and then it can be extended to whole domain (a,b).

Comment: I edited your examples into the post. It's usually more helpful if you give any partial progress you've made, because we can try to use your progress to help you finish the entire problem.

Comment: @nicomezi there are injective functions that are not surjective

Comment: Sorry I though "one-one" was a synonym of bijection. @AlvinLepik

Comment: For 4) let $a< c < d < e$ and let $f(c) =a$ and $f(d) = e$ and for the rest of the point in $(a,b)$ whatever allows the function to be continuous.  Example: For $c < x < d$ let $f(x) =a+ (x-c)\frac{b-a}{d-c}$ (that just "connects the dots".  For $a< x<c$ let $f(x)=a+(c-x)$ For $d< x$ let $f(x)=b-(x-d)$.  But note we can't have it be onto. For $f(w)=a$ then values below and above $w$ must "double up".

Comment: @fleablood I think it is sufficient to find a continuous surjection $(0,1) \to [0,1]$. Scaling is then considerably easier.

Comment: Yeah... I was trying to avoid being specific.  $\sin: (0,\pi)\to [-1,1]$ is surjective.  It's okay because although it gets all the way to extreme values.... it then just goes down again.

Comment: @fleablood that specific one isn't surjective, but I understand your point.

Comment: Oops.... $(0,2\pi)\to [-1,1]$.

Answer (score 1):

For 1) take any closed interval $[c,d]$ contained in $(a,b)$. Can you find  a homeomorphism from $[a,b]$ onto $[c,d]$? (There is one of the type $f(x)=\alpha x+\beta$).

For 3) the identity function is an example.

Comment: ok. Got it.........

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, can shrink the closed interval to fit in $(a,b)$.
2. As $f$ is continuous we must have $f([a,b])$ closed and bounded i.e compact.
3. Yes, the identity.
4. Yes, we can use the following continuous surjection (there are plenty of others, too) $(0,1) \to [0,1]$, $x\mapsto \frac{1}{2}\sin (4\pi x) + \frac{1}{2}$. Then a continuous surjection 
   $$(a,b)\to (0,1) \to [0,1] \to [a,b] $$
   is straightforward to find.

Comment: 4: must be closed *in the appropriate topology*. Here we are interested in the subspace topology on $(a,b)$, and $(a,b)$ is closed in that topology. Unless I have really badly messed up?

Comment: @PatrickStevens I think you're right, I must reconsider that point.

Comment: To be concrete: construct the function $(-1, 2) \to [-1, 2]$ by defining a continuous bijection $[0, 1] \to [-1, 2]$ and then defining whatever you like on $(-1, 0)$ and $(1, 2)$ as long as the endpoints are right and you don't escape $[-1, 2]$.

Comment: @PatrickStevens 4 is correct, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Not if $f$ is not one-to-one then $f$ can "double up".  If $f$ is not onto it doesn't have to "hit them all".  Your argument that the image of a compact set must be compact is good... if the function isn't onto the codomain need not be the image!

1)$f:[a,b]\to (a,b)$ is continuous and one to one.  It *seems* we want be able to get close to $\lim_{x\to w}f(w) =a$ without some issue.  But we don't have to!

If it's not onto it needn't hit all points.

Let $a < c < d < e$.   Let $f(a) = c$ and $f(d) = b$ and all the other points just do a linear stretch.  That is for $a\le x \le b$ let $f(x) = (x-a)\frac {d-c}{b-a} + c$.  That's one-to-one.

2) If $f$ is onto then the image *is* the codomain and your argument that a continuous image of a compact set is compact is valid.  This is in essence the Extreme value system.  This can not be done.

3) $f:(a,b)\to [a,b]$ is one-to-one.  But it doesn't have to be onto.  So it doesn't have to hit them all.

Let $a< c< d< b$ and let those $x$ that are "close" to $a$ have $f(x)$ "close" to $c$ and those "close" to $b$ have $f(x)$ "close" to $c$ so the image of $f$ is $(c,d)$ and $f$ just stretches between the points.  Like the function in 1).

That is for $a< x < b$ let $f(x) = (x-a)\frac {d-c}{b-a} + c$.  That's one-to-one.

(Hmmm.... even easier.... $f(x) = x$....The image is $(a,b)$.)

4) is different from $2$  A continuous function from a compact set must have a compact image, but a compact image needn't come from a compact set.  The function is onto but not one to one.  So for $f(w)=a$ we must have some $a< x< w$ where $f(x)$ is equal to some $f(y)$ for some $w< y$ but that's okay.

Let $a<c<d<b$ an let $f(c) =a$ and $f(d)=b$ and just stretch it out for the points between.  That is, for $c\le x\le d$ let $f(x) = (x-c)\frac {b-a}{d-c}$.  And for $x <  c$... welll do whatever you want.  Let $f(x)=a$ and for $x > d$ let $f(x)=b$.  Not one-to-one but onto.